# Gmail Adding STRANGE padding on rows after first row for my HTML signature

Tags: html-table, html-email, padding, signature, spaces

As the title suggests, if any other device receives the signature, it renders fine. but in gmail, it has this weird padding added to the rows.  but only the rows AFTER the first row.  The first row is perfect.  If anyone can help me figure this one out I would be greatful!

I know the gap color is green.  I use the green background to show me where there is a bleeding effects between the images.

```
<table border="0" bgcolor="green" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border: none;">
<tr>
    <td width="176" height="115" style="border:none">
        <img src="https://www.htref.co.za/signatures/images/img01-01.png" width="176" height="115">
    </td>
    <td width="623" height="115" style="border:none;">
        <img src="https://www.htref.co.za/signatures/images/img01.png" width="623" height="115">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="176" height="25" style="border:none;">
        <img src="https://www.htref.co.za/signatures/images/img02-01.png" width="176" height="25" style="display:block;">
    </td>
    <td width="623" height="25" style="border:none;">
        <img src="https://www.htref.co.za/signatures/images/img03-01.png" width="623" height="25" style="display:block;">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="176" height="25" style="border:none;">
        <img src="https://www.htref.co.za/signatures/images/img02-01.png" width="176" height="25" style="display:block;">
    </td>
    <td width="623" height="25" style="border:none;">
        <img src="https://www.htref.co.za/signatures/images/img03-01.png" width="623" height="25" style="display:block;">
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Example shown of gaps in the table rows:

[image]

Comment: Make sure you have given padding:0; to table rows.

Comment: If that was the problem, then the first row would also have a padding problem.

Comment: How about removing the height from the td's and adding display block to the top two images?